# Pass by ref is not effectively used inside body - PhpStorm, why is it "bad"?

Tags: php, reference, phpstorm

Why I was browsing my code with PhpStorm, I bumped into a "warning":

[image]

I know PhpStorm tries to offer "clean" way of coding, but that case I don't understand. What's wrong with that code? `$item` is `unset`-ted at the end of foreach.

Comment: please add the rest of the body to the question (_as text, not an image of text_) - is item updated? It's implied it is not.

Comment: oh yea, its not updated.... I was wrong.

Answer (score 3):

do you use the $item variable inside of your foreach loop? If not, there's no need to pass it by reference.